# How can I solve the differential equation $bv - mg = mv'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this simple differential equation?

$$bv - mg = mv'$$

I am new to physics with no background in differential functions math.

Is there any general "algorithm" to solve such equations?

thanks.

Comment: @Meowdog : The right side is a function of $v$ alone. This makes it separable.

Comment: You could either solve it as a separable equation (in this case you may have to take into account division by $0$), or solve it as a first order linear ODE using an integrating factor. See e.g. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/separable.aspx for the algorithm for the separable case, or https://weber.itn.liu.se/~krzma/DS2017/Integrating%20factor%20method.pdf for the integrating factor method.

Comment: Sorry, I have to walk back on my last comment. It is indeed separable. Not nice to compute though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linear ODE

$$mv'=bv-mg \implies v'-\frac{b}{m}v=-g$$

Multiplying the expression by the integrating factor $e^{-\frac{b}{m}t}$, we obtain

\begin{align}
v'e^{-\frac{b}{m}t}-\frac{b}{m}ve^{-\frac{b}{m}t}&=-ge^{-\frac{b}{m}t} \\
\implies \frac{d}{dt}(ve^{-\frac{b}{m}t})&=-ge^{-\frac{b}{m}t} \\
\implies ve^{-\frac{b}{m}t}&=-g\int e^{-\frac{b}{m}t}dt \\
\implies ve^{-\frac{b}{m}t}&=g\frac{m}{b}e^{-\frac{b}{m}t}+c \\
\implies v&=g\frac{m}{b}+ce^{\frac{b}{m}t}, \quad c \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}

To answer the question, you can apply this integrating factor procedure to solve any linear ODE of the form $y'=ay+b$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: (+1) More generally, you could take $a$ and $b$ to be any continuous functions of the independent variable to apply the integrating factor procedure.

Comment: Indeed. On that situation, the exponent of the integrating factor would be minus a primitive of the coefficient of $y$, i.e., if the equation is $y'=a(t)y+b(t)$, the integrating factor would be $e^{-\int a(t)\, dt}$. Thanks for the 
clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @JaviLark01's great answer: There is a general formula for the solution of
$$
v'(t) = a(t)v(t)+b(t),
$$
where $a, b:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. A solution with $v(t_0) = x_0$ ($x_0, t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$) is always given by
$$
v(t) = \left(x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} \exp\left(-\int^s_{t_0} a(r)~\mathrm{d}r \right)b(s)~\mathrm{d}s \right)\exp\left(\int^s_{t_0} a(r)~\mathrm{d}r \right).
$$