# How do I solve this simple ODE with $\cos$ and $\cot$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

I'm new to Ordinary DIfferential Equation and I need to find the general solution to this problem:

$$\dot{x} = 2\cos{t} - x\cot{t}, (t, x) \in [0, \pi] \times \mathbb{R}$$

I don't know where to start, given that I don't have an initial condition, is there something that I'm missing? Is there a possible substitution?

Comment: This is first order linear differential equation.

Comment: There is a formula for equations like these. Look at [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484780/how-can-i-solve-the-differential-equation-bv-mg-mv/4485003#4485003) here

Comment: Thank you guys.

Comment: @Gonçalo, Why I can't use Meowdog solution directly? Shouldn't it give me the general solution directly?

Comment: Oh , I see it now, In thi case we would, rewrite the problem to make it simpler to solve, you've "partitioned" in two homogenous solutions, because solving the problem for $v(t)$ would lead to the same path.

Comment: Btw, The homogenous solution can be written as: $x_h(t) = c \exp(A(t))$, where $A(t)$ is a primitive for $- \cot{t }$, right?

Comment: You're right, im not good with memorizing things to, I'll adopt you're approach, thank you